# Early Stop callback in keras

Tags: keras, callback, early-stopping

How can one effectively stop the fit process of a training model via callback in keras? Thus far I have tried various approaches including the one below.

```
class EarlyStoppingCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, threshold):
        super(EarlyStoppingCallback, self).__init__()
        self.threshold = threshold

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        accuracy = logs["accuracy"]
        if accuracy >= self.threshold:
            print("Stopping early!")
            self.model.stop_training = True
```

The callback is executed, however the `self.model.stop_training = True` does not seem to have an effect. The print succeeds, but the model continues training. Any idea how to resolve this issue?
My tensorflow version is: tensorflow==1.14.0

Comment: Could you share a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably affected by the following issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37587.

In short - whenever `model.predict` or `model.evaluate` are called, `model.stop_training` is reset to `False`. I was able to reproduce this behavior using your `EarlyStoppingCallback` followed by another callback which was calling `model.predict` on some fixed dataset.

The workaround is to put callbacks which are calling `model.predict` or `model.evaluate` first before any callbacks which might want to set `model.stop_training` to `True`. It also looks like the issue was fixed in TF 2.2.

Comment: Thank you :), this was very insightful. Problem could be immediately fixed.